# Is it possible to adjust radeon integrated graphics memory at runtime?

Tags: gpu, amd-graphics

I have a Radeon 680M, an integrated AMD GPU. I do games sometimes, and would prefer to have more memory allocated to GPU when I do. There is a BIOS setting to adjust the GPU memory, but closing all the windows and restarting every time to apply the allocation is inconvenient.

Is there a way to adjust the GPU memory allocation without sorting to the BIOS setting and restart?

The BIOS has an option as "AUTO", which I assume would allow the OS to adjust the GPU memory. "AUTO" would get me about 1GB of GPU memory without me doing anything extra. The GPU memory does not auto-expand when I launch graphics-demanding games.

FWIW I tried setting `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/mem_info_vram_total` directly but that apparently is read-only. There are a few more vram related files there, but all read-only.